# Export to excel in asp.net using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I am using following example on [Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) website  to exports data from sql server to Excel sheet i slightly modified the example to use `datatable` for my version while debugging it loops through all the rows but it only show one last row in actual excel file

Below is the code for vs 2010, I am sure i did miss something

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   // rowCounter++;
    workSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = row["Date"];
    workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = row["Title"];
    workSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = row["Description"];
}
    ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[1]).AutoFit();
    ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[2]).AutoFit();
    ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[3]).AutoFit();
```

How can i also modify this code so that it write output to `Download_Excel.xls` file

Above code only show last one row in excel.
**OUTPUT** 
[image]

It doesn't custom  Title as either.

TWO MISTAKE I WAS DOING.

First `ROWINDEX`  was starting from 1  so i set `ROWINDEX= 2` and things worked fine

**WORKING CODE**

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    rowCounter++;
    workSheet.Cells[rowCounter, "A"] = row["Date"];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCounter, "B"] = row["Title"];
    workSheet.Cells[rowCounter, "C"] = row["Description"];
}

    string fileName = "Product.xls";
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    workSheet.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../"+fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change the index along the way. Right now you are always overwriting row 1, make keep increasing it with each row.

Comment: It works, but but  header is still missing let me start my row index from 2 may be that will fix issue..